# Magento 2: Keep old data on Magento 2 Data Migration Tool after migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Well, actually can someones could give the example of Magento 2 Data Migration Tool.
Here order migration for example.

**while I want to keeps all old created orders on Magento 2 site,**

After migration, I should have both old orders and new orders which already migrated from Magento 1 database.

Answer (score 0):

Migration Tool Working like this.

1. You Perform Migration today, then it transfer the data from magneto1 to Magento2.
2. After some days, Now on the same setup you perform `Delta Migration` step only, so this Migrated newly data from Magento1 to Magneto2.

For More Information check this one : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: Thanks @Dhiren seem you are talking about delta migration, yeah but the point is not what I want to archive.